# JS access to Spring REST services behind ZUUL blocked by CORS policy

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, spring-cloud, netflix-zuul

I am putting together a small service-based platform using various Spring Cloud frameworks. The individual components are as follows:

- an Eureka discovery server
- a Spring-Config server
- an Authentication server
- a Zuul gateway server
- a REST service
- a PostgreSQL server
- a simple JQuery-based client running in the browser

(yes this is based on the design presented in Manning's "Spring Microservices in Action")

This all works just fine in development. However I have recently deployed all this server-side stuff to an external server (running docker-compose) and I can no longer access the service endpoints.

When calling the service endpoints via JQuery I get the following error:

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://my.domain.com/api/resource/123/subresource/456' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I have tried adding the following to the Zuul server (in the same @EnableZuulProxy Spring boot application class) :

```
@Bean
public FilterRegsitrationBean corsFilter() {

    UrlBaseCorsConfigurationSource source = 
        new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();

    CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();

    config.setAllowCredentials(true);

    config.addAllowedOrigin("*");
    config.addAllowedHeader("*");
    config.addAllowedMethod("*");

    source.registerCorsConfiguration("*", config);

    FilterRegistrationBean<CorsFilter> bean = 
        new FilterRegistrationBean<>(new CorsFilter(source));

    bean.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);

    return bean;
}
```

This yielded the same error.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so I fixed it by removing all Cors configs from the services and added this to the Zuul gateway.

```
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {

        registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedMethods("POST", "PUT", "GET", "OPTIONS", "DELETE", "HEAD");
    }
}
```

It works but I have no idea why my previous attempts don't (and I obviously hate fixing something without having understood how). So if anyone has any ideas...

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

In Controller, you need to add another annotation with @RestController/@Controller.

@CrossOrigin

Like this :

```
@Controller
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", allowedHeaders = "*")
public class HomeController
```

Try this one.

Comment: Afraid not. I tried that and get the exact same error message in the console :(